# seeking deeper understanding on the powershell -replace magic

Tags: regex, powershell, syntax

I can replace a substring in a string using PowerShell like this in a very C# way:

```
$s.replace("foo", "bar")
```

This works fine and uses no regular expressions, making it easy to grasp.

However, this also works (this does use regular expressions)

```
$s -replace "foo", "bar"
```

The mystery to me here is the syntax. Is the string object magically listening to a "-replace" command line parameter? Where does this come from? What is this dark magic?

I'd like to simply gain more understanding of the PowerShell ways and perhaps figure out if more of this voodoo applies to other objects or the string object itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-replace` is a Powershell operator. Learn more about Powershell operators here - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847732.aspx

It has almost nothing to do with the string object doing something, but has to do with Powershell as a scripting language. While it leverages .NET objects and hence their properties and methods ( which is where String.Replace comes into picture), Powershell also has its own syntax that it brings to the table.

Answer (score 0):

> What is this dark magic?

The PowerShell interpreter understands the `a -replace b,c` operator and knows to call [`Regex.Replace(a, b, c)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f5w83z.aspx) (with the right case matching option).